# Python BeautifulSoup combine array elements from two array from HTML site

Tags: python, arrays, beautifulsoup, request, python-re

I created a script to get data from HTML website. I use beautiful soup with the main purpose of achieving web scrabbing. I wanted to get data from JavaScript variables which is found in the HTML website. There are two arrays and I want to extract the values from two arrays and put in the python array to view the data. Unfortunately the website is not available online.

Here is my code below

```
#Import module to achieve the respective function
import requests, bs4, re
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
script = soup.find('script')
result = re.search("var\sjHst=.*]];", str(script))
result1 = re.search("var\s types=.*]];, str(script))
if result1:
    print ("MATCH for types")
else:
    print ("no match for types")
if result:
    print ("MATCH for jHst")
else:
    print ("no match for jHst")

for ef in script:
    all_value =  ef        
    if all_value:            
        m = p.match(all_value)
        print m
```

Here is the Javascript code which is inside the HTML. The type variable is the header while the jHst is the table content which consisted of data.

```
</table>
</html>
<script language="JavaScript1.2"><!--
var types=['-','Print','Copy','Scan','Retrieve from Folder','Fax','Report']; 
var jHst=[['TEST.pdf','abcd',1,1,20,'Center Tray - Lower','LPD','26/10/2020 11:04'],['resumeform.docx','10.50.121.0',1,1,2,'Center Tray - Lower','Port 9100','22/10/2020 07:58']];
```

I am thinking of how to load values to array like this below.

```
Header header header header header
values values values values values
```

I performed the beautifulsoup to get the data such as HTML and javascript. Then I performed a regular expression to find variable "var jHst" and "var types". If available, I wanted to try loading the two array into 1 array but I am stuck on how to get data for the respective variables and load into array. I know that we need to use append python command to achieve loading data to array but how to get data from the site and load it.  Please kindly help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the javascript variables into python lists, you can use `re` and [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). For example:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

txt = '''</table>
</html>
<script language="JavaScript1.2"><!--
var types=['-','Print','Copy','Scan','Retrieve from Folder','Fax','Report']; 
var jHst=[['TEST.pdf','abcd',1,1,20,'Center Tray - Lower','LPD','26/10/2020 11:04'],['resumeform.docx','10.50.121.0',1,1,2,'Center Tray - Lower','Port 9100','22/10/2020 07:58']];
'''

types = literal_eval( re.search(r'var types=(\[.*\]);', txt).group(1) )
jHst = literal_eval( re.search(r'var jHst=(\[.*\]);', txt).group(1) )

print(types)
print(jHst)
```

Prints:

```
['-', 'Print', 'Copy', 'Scan', 'Retrieve from Folder', 'Fax', 'Report']
[['TEST.pdf', 'abcd', 1, 1, 20, 'Center Tray - Lower', 'LPD', '26/10/2020 11:04'], ['resumeform.docx', '10.50.121.0', 1, 1, 2, 'Center Tray - Lower', 'Port 9100', '22/10/2020 07:58']]
```

Comment: Hi @Andrej Kesely, thanks for the commands but I was asking whether is it possible to combine the two python list..

Comment: @JohnnyLim you can combine the lists, for example `out = [types, jHst]`. Or make a dictionary `out = {'types': types, 'jHst': jHst}`